# BizTalk 2010 Parties not available to enlist in Role Link

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, trading

I'm having an issue when modifying an existing BizTalk 2010 application.  The application currently takes a flat file, maps the data in the file to an EDI 835 format, and then a Role Link determines which Party/Send Port to use to complete building the 835 and dropping it in the correct folder.  This application was actually upgraded from a BizTalk 2006 R2 project, and the parties were migrated over using the Party Migration Tool included with BizTalk 2010.  This application has worked fine since the migration.

As part of some new requirements, we are adding a couple of new parties and modifying some of the existing parties.  I have already gone ahead and created the new parties and agreements in the BizTalk 2010 Server Administration Console.  However, when I get to the step of enlisting the new parties with the existing Role Link, the new parties do not show up in the list of available parties to be enlisted.  I have tried restarting the host instances and refreshing the BizTalk group multiple times in an attempt to get BizTalk to refresh the list, but that has not worked.  I have also attempted to repair the BizTalk installation thinking that maybe the installation was to blame.  That did not work either.

After some research, I found that the data in the BizTalkMgmtDb database is out of sync.  It appears there are two places where parties can be found.  There are the TPM tables, which have the parties all listed under the Partner table, and the BusinessIdentity table appears to have all of the latest data I entered.  Looking at the dbo.bts_party table however does not have the latest data, and the new parties are missing.  Other tables related to this dbo.bts_party table are also missing the latest data.

It looks like older versions of BizTalk had a way of keeping TPM and BizTalk in sync using something called Business Activity Services (BAS).  I don't see anything like that in BizTalk 2010 however.  Has anyone ever run into this issue before, and how would I go about solving it?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would put up a response here for anyone who might stumble across this.  Unfortunately I had to spend the weekend reinstalling BizTalk, which we were trying to avoid.  This resolved the issue, though I did avoid using the Party Migration Tool this time and just recreated everything from scratch.